# Combine date and time string into single date with javascript

Tags: javascript, date

I have a [datepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/datepicker) returning a date string, and a [timepicker](http://mgcrea.github.io/angular-strap/#/timepicker) returning just a time string.

How should I combine those into a single javascript Date?

I thought I found a solution in [Date.js](https://code.google.com/p/datejs/). The examples shows an `at( )`-method, but I can't find it in the library...

Comment: can you addin a small code snippet or jsfiddle that shows an example with actual and expected values?

Comment: If you follow the link to the datepicker and timepicker, there are actual working samples of both.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can configure your date picker to return format like `YYYY-mm-dd` (or any format that [`Date.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) supports) and you could build a string in timepicker like:

```
 var dateStringFromDP = '2013-05-16';

 $('#timepicker').timepicker().on('changeTime.timepicker', function(e) {
    var timeString = e.time.hour + ':' + e.time.minute + ':00';
    var dateObj = new Date(datestringFromDP + ' ' + timeString);
  });
```

javascript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) object takes a string as the constructor param

Comment: Even if I set the format for the datepicker (like `data-date-format="dd. MM yyyy"`) the value set to the scope is a date, not a string. I managed to get what I wanted with the following code: `Date.parse($scope.date.toString("dd.MM.yyyy") + " " + $scope.fromTime);`

Comment: This may not work in Safari. I tried running `new Date('2018-10-30 10:00')` in Safari 12 and got `Invalid Date` back. Safari can parse `new Date('2018-10-30T10:00')` but that will produce a different result than other browsers (see my comment to Jan.J's answer).

Answer (score 18):

Combine date and time to string like this:

```
1997-07-16T19:20:15
```

Then you can parse it like this:

```
Date.parse('1997-07-16T19:20:15');
```

You could also use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) or something similar.

Comment: moment.js is a lifesaver

Comment: Be careful with this. I ran `new Date('2018-10-30T10:00')` in Safari and got `Tue Oct 30 2018 03:00:00 GMT-0700 (PDT)`. But I ran the same thing in Chrome and got `Tue Oct 30 2018 10:00:00 GMT-0700 (Pacific Daylight Time)`. It seems that Safari interprets the time as UTC, and most other browsers interpret it as whatever the browser's time zone is.

Answer (score 7):

For plain JavaScript:

```
combineDateAndTime = function(date, time) {
    timeString = time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + ':00';

    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // Jan is 0, dec is 11
    var day = date.getDate();
    var dateString = '' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    var combined = new Date(dateString + ' ' + timeString);

    return combined;
};
```

Comment: What does the `'' + ` in front of `year` in the row where you concatinate the `dateString` do? Since it doesn't contain a space, it shouldn't do anything.

Comment: @shaedrich seems you are right it doesn't need that at least in a quick test on https://playcode.io/new/. I'm guessing at the time it was to force string concatenation, seems it may not have been necessary.

Answer (score 6):

You can concatenate the date and time, and then use moment to get the `datetime`

```
const date = '2018-12-24';
const time = '23:59:59';

const dateTime = moment(`${date} ${time}`, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').format();
```

Answer (score 3):

Boateng's example fails in cases where time consisted of hours, minutes, days or months that ranged from values 0-9 as getDate(), getMonth() etc... will return 1 digit in these cases and the time string will fail and an invalid date is returned:

```
function CombineDateAndTime(date, time) {
     const mins = ("0"+ time.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
     const hours = ("0"+ time.getHours()).slice(-2);
     const timeString = hours + ":" + mins + ":00";
     const year = date.getFullYear();
     const month = ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
     const day = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
     const dateString = "" + year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
     const datec = dateString + "T" + timeString;
     return new Date(datec);
};
```

Unfortunately do not have enough rep to comment

Comment: You can now use [`padStart()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart) to simplify your solution like that: `time.getMinutes().toString().padStart(2, '0')`

Answer (score 1):

David's example with slight modifications:

```
function CombineDateAndTime(date, time) {
    var timeString = time.getHours() + ':' + time.getMinutes() + ':00';
    var ampm = time.getHours() >= 12 ? 'PM' : 'AM';
    var year = date.getFullYear();
    var month = date.getMonth() + 1; // Jan is 0, dec is 11
    var day = date.getDate();
    var dateString = '' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    var datec = dateString + 'T' + timeString;
    var combined = new Date(datec);

    return combined;
};
```

Comment: Are you using `ampm` somewhere else in the code? It would only make sense if you also convert a 24 hours based hour to a 12 hours based hour.

Answer (score 1):

Concate date and time with moment JS which also works on **firefox**,

```
let d1 = moment().format('MM/DD/YYYY');
let dateTimeOpen = moment(d1 + ' ' + model.openingTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
let dateTimeClose = moment(d1 + ' ' + model.closingTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const date = "2022-12-27";
const time = "16:26:42";

new Date(`${date}T${time});
```

output

```
Date Tue Dec 27 2022 16:26:42 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```