# Convert separate date and time to timestamp in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

How can I convert date and time which are collected separately into a timestamp in react?
Currently, I'm changing the input type to date onFocus and time is collected the same way. I want to combine these 2 and make a timestamp. Any ideas?

```
<input 
   placeholder="Pickup Date"
   onFocus={this.handleDate}
   type="text"
   id="pickupDate"
   onChange={this.handleChange} 
   required />
```

Comment: Can you provide the code for `this.handledate`?

Comment: What is your definition of "timestamp"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if i understood clearly question you can use moment.js library

```
import moment from 'moment'

const date = '2019/02/02'
const time = '12:20'
const timestamp = moment.utc(`${date} ${time}`).unix()
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the question is, how to do that with javascript, take a look on that:
[Combine date and time string into single date with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16597853/combine-date-and-time-string-into-single-date-with-javascript)

the most voted answer. These values you can take inside the handleDate method and you combine with your time value to apply the `new Date(date + ' ' + hour)`

Answer (score 0):

Be more specific about what you want
**Send picture or code**